# changing non character letters in selected variables

Tags: r

I've got a data frame with text. I'd like to change all "," to "-" in all observations of selected variables, and like to select the variables based on their names containing the word date.

I've tried to incorporate various variations of grep() expressions into MyFunc but haven't been able to get it to work.

Thanks!

starting point:

```
df <- data.frame(dateofbirth=c("25,06,1939","15,04,1941","21,06,1978","06,07,1946","14,07,1935"),recdate=c("26,06,1945","03,04,1964","21,06,1949","15,07,1923","07,12,1945"),b=c("8,ted,st","99,tes,rd","6,ldk,dr","2,sdd,jun","asd,2,st"),disdatenow=c("25,06,1975","25,05,1996","21,06,1932","26,07,1934","07,07,1965"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

desired outcome:

```
df <- data.frame(dateofbirth=c("25-06-1939","15-04-1941","21-06-1978","06-07-1946","14-07-1935"),recdate=c("26-06-1945","03-04-1964","21-06-1949","15-07-1923","07-12-1945"),b=c("8,ted,st","99,tes,rd","6,ldk,dr","2,sdd,jun","asd,2"),disdatenow=c("25-06-1975","25-05-1996","21-06-1932","26-07-1934","07-07-1965"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Current code:

```
MyFunc <- function(x) {gsub(",","-",df$x)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mutate_at` from `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(contains("date")), function(x){gsub(",", "-", x)})
```

and that gives you this:

```
  dateofbirth    recdate         b disdatenow
1  25-06-1939 26-06-1945  8,ted,st 25-06-1975
2  15-04-1941 03-04-1964 99,tes,rd 25-05-1996
3  21-06-1978 21-06-1949  6,ldk,dr 21-06-1932
4  06-07-1946 15-07-1923 2,sdd,jun 26-07-1934
5  14-07-1935 07-12-1945  asd,2,st 07-07-1965
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your function `MyFunc`, this should also work

```
MyFunc <- function(x) {gsub(",", "-", x)}
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
cols <- c("dateofbirth", "recdate", "disdatenow")
df[, cols] <- df[, lapply(.SD, MyFunc), .SDcols = cols]
```